# Add dynamic dependencies to a Play application after it's built

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, classloader, playframework-2.6

I distribute my Play app as a server which is run by my customers on-prem. One of the features I publish is a server-side API, enabling them to drop-in code that runs in the server's address space. This code is compiled as a jar file and dropped into the directory `ext/` created by my install, at the same level as the regular `lib/` directory.

The problem is that I don't have a good way to make these dependencies found by the class loader. I've written a custom class loader, which works fine, so long as it's my code that does the loading. Which is the case when I instantiate top-level custom classes, but not further down the chain, e.g. a JDBC driver or a Kafka client, dependent on by client code.

The stopgap solution I've found is to append `:/path/to/server/ext/*` to the long, hard-coded (for a good reason - I get it) list of `app-classpath` inside the application bootup bash script (line 341 in 2.6). Wondering if there isn't a better solution. For instance, why not honor the `classpath` env variable?

Or something else altogether?

Comment: I'm not clear understand your situation, but maybe you need to use something like OSGI instead of custom classloader?

Comment: Nah, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to differentiate is a PATH between development, deployment, why not add your environment variable to `application.conf`:

```
my.majestic.path="/blah/blah"
```

This can be overwritten by the customer within the `conf` folder to add that path.

**More Scalable Solution**: If your customers are big boys and girls who use clusters to deal with applications (such as Kubernetes) then you can have this:

```
my.majestic.path="/blah/blah"
my.majestic.path=${?MY_MAJESTIC_PATH}
```

Then the `MY_MAJESTIC_PATH` will be overwritten during the production within the cluster management. This should be handled by the customers.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. I don't see how this solves my problem, i.e. how `my.majestic.path` gets added to the server's classpath _after_ it is built.